Gas log replacement
We have been in our house for 22 years, and now want to replace the (presumably ceramic) gas logs that were in the fireplace when we moved in. I thought it was simply a matter of placing new ceramic logs on top of the rack where the old logs were, but I've been reading about how flames should not directly come into contact with gas logs. However, that's exactly what was happening with the old logs for many years.
So my question is this: Is this true about flames contacting gas logs? Or does it depend on the logs we purchase?
Pictured is our fireplace. It has a metal firebox with a damper above it and a gas valve in the wall adjacent to it. The burner holes are pointed downward and so the flames deflect off the base and back upward toward the rack and logs.


I think it does depend on the logs.  Look for logs designed to work with your fireplace set up.
